# How do pointers to arrays of integers work in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Take a look at this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};   // LINE A
    int (*b)[5] = &a;         // LINE B
    printf("%d\n", (*b)[0]);  // LINE C
}
```

1. I tried writing `int (*b)[5] = a` on `LINE B` but it didn't work. Can anyone explain why this didn't work? I though arrays decayed into pointers, so I can't quite understand why I needed to explicitly take address of `a` via `&a`. It's like `a` already is a pointer because it decayed, but now I take a address of a pointer? Double pointer? Huh?
2. Can anyone explain how `(*b)[0]` works? It's like I dereference `b`, which is itself a pointer to array of 5 ints, but I somehow take [0]'th element of it? Isn't the [0]-th element in this case 5 integers? I somehow end up with one integer though and it prints `1`.

I'm really confused. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Array decays to a pointer to its first element, not a pointer to itself. 2) If you dereference a "pointer to array of 5 ints", you get a "array of 5 ints", that you then index with `[0]`.

Comment: Arrays decay only if not operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof` (C11), `&` (which applies in your case), or for string literals used in an array initializer.

Comment: @mafso this does not apply to `_Alignof` as `_Alignof` operand is a type-name and cannot be an expression. The draft version of c11 is buggy and has been corrected in the release version of c11.

Comment: @ouah: True enough! Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

-------In Memory----------
| 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 |
---------------------------                                         
101   105  109  113  117  //Assume these are addresses
```

By default Array Names act like pointers to there first element.
So `a` acts like pointer to first element(here element is integer)

so `a` is decayed into `int *a`;
thats why if you increment by one then it will jump to next addresses of element, as shown below
It will calculate like this: **Address of 1st element + (n * sizeof(int))**

```
(a+0)--->101  // 101 + 0*sizeof(int)
(a+1)--->105 //  101 + 1*sizeof(int)
(a+2)--->109 //  101 + 2*sizeof(int)
(a+3)--->113 //  101 + 3*sizeof(int)
(a+4)--->117 //  101 + 4*sizeof(int)
```

But `&a` acts like a pointer to complete array(in this case pointer to 5 ints), that means
when you add one to it,then it will try to point to next 5 integers.As shown below

```
(&a+1)----->121 //101 + 1*sizeof(a)
```

Thats why in this line`int (*b)[5] = &a;` there is no problem,But when you try `int(*b)[5]=a;`
it gives error because **`a` is pointer to single integer where as (*b)[5] is pointer to 5 integers**.You cannot assign incompatible pointers types.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a pointer to array `a`. Dereferencing `b` will give the entire array `a`. So, when you will use `*b` in an expression, it represents the name for that dereferenced array. Since array names are converted to pointer to first element of array, `*b` decays to pointer to first element of `a` (or `*b`).  `*b` has type `int *` after decay. Therefore `(*b)[i]` will give the i<sup>th</sup> element of the array that `b` points to.

Comment: There's no need to decay to a pointer to make this work, array indexing works without it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: To be completely pedantic, as far as the standard is concerned, the array has decayed in this scenario (see C99, 6.3.2.1 p3).

Answer (score -4):

When you declare - int a[5] - the compiler is using 'a' as a reference to the internal memory. 'a' itself is not a variable. Thus, &a does not work.

Comment: `a` is very much a variable.